# Obsolate postgresql version 15 on Kali

Tags: kali-linux, postgresql

I'm begginer who tries to start working with Kali Linux so I downloaded virtual box, then kali, but after command 'sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt update' I got message that postgresql 15 is obsolute. I tried to download Kali from other site (firstly I downloaded this from kali.org), but it didnt solve the problem, I have the same message and after spending much time, trying to find the solution, I'm finally here, begging for help, Thank You for every answer

Comment: Complementing the answer below: If you're a beginner, in Kali or any other distro, you shouldn't be using `-y` because you want to read and understand all messages before accepting the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The current PostgreSQL package for Kali is [`postgresql-16`](https://pkg.kali.org/pkg/postgresql-16):

```
sudo apt install postgresql-16
```

Given that you’re a beginner, please check [this section of the Kali documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#is-kali-linux-right-for-you); you would probably be better off with another distribution.

Comment: Yes, I know that its maybe too hard for a begginer, but I really would like to try at least... so please help me - after install command i get communicate "Waiting for cache lock: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is he"

Comment: @MichałTlałka You should get experience with normal Linux distros before jumping to Kali. It's not a normal distro, it has a very narrow applicability and anyone using it is expected to 1. know exactly that and 2. be able to solve trivial Linux issues, namely understand the meaning of the message you just quoted. Please read and understand the link included in this answer.

Comment: Okey, thank you. I'll try with another linux

Comment: Although what was said above is true, here is an answer from someone who remember where he started. A: This means another instance of dpkg or a frontend is running, so the correct solutions are to:

    Let the other process end its execution,
    Find the frontend and quit it,
    Check whether there is any periodic job (via cron or systemd timers) that calls dpkg or a frontend and disable them, or
    Kill any such frozen processes. 

See Dpkg FAQ for more detail on how to resolve. https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#db-lock